# How can I track time on a website from multiple IPs

Tags: laptop, history, desktop-computer, tracking

I was wondering if there is a way to track time on a certain web site from my local computers / devices here. I wanna track from iPods, iPhones, laptops, desktops, etc to lets say facebook.com or twitter.com. If it helps, I have Comcast cable and a Linksys E2500 router.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about possible ways to monitor how much time these devices spend browsing given web sites during some period? If so, a possible approach is to set up an HTTP proxy.